# Setting the prompt in Beeline

Tags: hive

When connecting to beeline, my prompt is some hefty truncated version of the JDBC url:

`0: jdbc:hive2//fully.qualified.host.na`

Which takes up an annoying amount of real estate.
I tried `set hive.cli.prompt=foo>>`, and get an error that that property is not in the list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime.

Is there no way to set the prompt to a custom values?

Comment: The only mention of the "prompt" in the Beeline manual is about a _"show DB in prompt"_ command-line option, cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients and its link to HIVE-14123 *(which in turn links to other legacy `hive.cli` client-side properties that Beeline does not honor)*

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

For hive, you can set hive.cli.prompt;  for beeline it is hardcoded here:

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/477f541844db3ea5eaee8746033bf80cd48b7f8c/beeline/src/java/org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLine.java#L1769-L1775

Comment: If I run this command:  `beeline --outputformat=$outputFormat --hiveconf cliprompt=">" -u <url>`, it seems to behave, but it isn't actually connecting.  If I take away the `--hiveconf cliprompt=">"` part, it works as expected, I just end up with the long prompt.

Comment: After paying a little more attention, I get this back in the response:`Failed to open new session: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot modify cliprompt at runtime.`

Comment: Oops, I forgot the hive.config prefix on the property.